# Custom Framework working in iPhone 4S/5 and iPad simulator and not in iPhone 5s/6/6Plus/6s/6sPlus

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, frameworks

I imported the Haneke framework to the my project, but it doesn't work. I got an error "use of unresolved identifier..." related to Haneke framework. But when I switch the simulator to the 4s/5 or iPad it works fine.. For some reason it was not importing anything from the framework.
I tried with all the simulator devices and found out that it's working for 4S/5/iPad. and not for 5s/6/6+/iPad Retina. I though the problem was in the framework, so I ran the sample code with that framework and it worked perfectly fine on all the simulator devices. So there is nothing that framework is supporting specific devices.
Help me please, because I don't know where is the problem

Comment: I could imagine that this is a 32/64bit-related issue as the iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 are the last 32bit iPhones, though I don't know anything about that framework to confirm it

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=HanekeSwift).

It is designed to work and load on all devices that run **iOS 8+**, and is in **Swift 2.0**.

**Podfile**

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'HanekeSwift'
```